# How to create a view whose positions can be changed by accelerometer in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have tried the following method by testing out the data binding first before introducing in accelerometer:

Path.RenderTransform TransformGroup data binding is not working. As I click on the button, the label will change but nothing changes in the path. The path still changes shape if I give it an arbitrary number.

```
            <Button Text="Increase Y Position" Command="{Binding IncreaseCommand}" />
            <AbsoluteLayout>
                <Path Fill="Blue"
                       Stroke="Red">
                    <Path.Data>
                        <EllipseGeometry 
                            Center="{Binding CircleLocation}"
                                         RadiusX="10"
                                         RadiusY="10"/>
                    </Path.Data>
                </Path>
            </AbsoluteLayout>            

            <Path Stroke="Black"
                  Aspect="Uniform"
                  HorizontalOptions="Center"
                  HeightRequest="100"
                  WidthRequest="100"
                  Data="omitted for brievity">
                <Path.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <ScaleTransform ScaleY="{Binding YPosition}"/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </Path.RenderTransform>
            </Path>
```

in view model

```
    public AnimationViewModel()
    {
      IncreaseCommand = new Command(IncreaseCount);
    }

    public System.Windows.Input.ICommand  IncreaseCommand { get; }

    void IncreaseCount()
    {
      yPosition++ ;
      OnPropertyChanged(nameof(DisplayCount));
      OnPropertyChanged(nameof(YPosition));
    }
    public double DisplayCount => yPosition;
    public double YPosition
    {
      get => yPosition;
      set
      {
        if (yPosition == value)
          return;

        yPosition = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(YPosition));
        // OnPropertyChanged(nameof(RectParameter));
      }
    }
```

using `TranslateTransform` causes arbitrary number not working, either, even in the official [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/userinterface-shapesdemos/). Binding did not work, either. Binding to a slider source work though, but that is not comptaible with accelerometer.

```
                    <TranslateTransform X="50"
                                        Y="50" />
```

Comment: Try to changing `yPosition++` to `YPosition++` in `IncreaseCount` method.

Comment: thanks! changed but i am afraid the shape is still not changing. @JackHua-MSFT

Comment: Can you please share me a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? I get some errors when I run your codes.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. I was trying to bind a `RotateTransform` to a property in my ViewModel but nothing worked. I started with the following XAML. I created temporary properties/bindings for `StrokeThickness` and `StrokeColor` to confirm that binding to the ViewModel was working and hardcoding the angle in the XAML also worked.

```
<Path StrokeThickness="{Binding StrokeThickness}" 
      Stroke="{Binding StrokeColor}"
      StrokeLineCap="Round"
      Data="M194.5,500 V 280" >
    <Path.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform CenterX="194.5" CenterY="280" Angle="{Binding Direction}" />
    </Path.RenderTransform>
</Path>
```

I tried a number of variations but I couldn't get the `Angle` to bind. Finally I created a new `Transform` property and created the transform in my ViewModel which worked successfully:

```
public Transform RotateTransform
{
    get
    {
        return new RotateTransform(45, 194.5, 280);
    }
}
```

With updated XAML:

```
<Path StrokeThickness="{Binding StrokeThickness}" 
      Stroke="{Binding StrokeColor}"
      StrokeLineCap="Round"
      Data="M194.5,500 V 280"
      RenderTransform="{Binding RotateTransform}" />
```